# converting scanned pdf to readable pdf

Tags: python-3.x, text, nlp, text-mining, pdf-conversion

I am trying to convert scanned pdf to readable pdf and I am using below code for the same. Firstly, I am converting the scanned document into an image and writing it back to blank pdf. It is giving output for the pdf which is not having any tables but it is not creating any images for the pdf containing tables.

```
from pdf2jpg import pdf2jpg
import pytesseract

source = "C://convertpdf//source"
destination = "C://convertpdf//dest"
pdf2jpg.convert_pdf2jpg(source, destination, pages="ALL")

text = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(image, lang='eng')
target_path = "C://pdfconvert//readblepdf//new.pdf"
with open(target_path, 'wb') as tmp_pdf:
    tmp_pdf.write(text)
tmp_pdf.close()
```

I would like to get the pdf with tables also get converted to the image and subsequently to readable one. is there any other package or methods in pdf2image that will do the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tesseract to generate searchable pdf as follows: (make sure you have eng.traineddata in your path)

```
tesseract words.png out -l eng PDF
```

Comment: I need to first convert scanned pdf to image which is not supported by tesseract

Answer (score 0):

pdf2jpg.convert_pdf2jpg(source, destination, pages="ALL")

converts PDF to image

Comment: it is only converting text as I mentioned